# What could this wallet be used for? Mining? Exchange?

Tags: etherscan

I was browsing etherscan and I found this wallet that has 10s of millions of dollars worth of ETH . I was going through their transaction history and they just have chunks of ETH coming from a bunch of different wallets consistently.

Is it exchange or mining related? I can't seem to find any mention of the address anywhere. I figured if it would've been flagged or mentioned online if it were exchange related.

Just trying to learn.

Here's a screenshot sample:
[image]

Going out too...
[image]

Comment: can you share the address?

Comment: @AdamBoudj here's the address 0xCbffCB2c38ecd19468d366D392AC0c1DC7F04Bb6

i think it it's an OKX exchange wallet, but correct me if wrong.